# connect mysql with c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm building a c# windows application which will connect with the mysql database in a remote server.

I'm using the following connect script

```
string connectionString;
connectionString = "SERVER = eu5.org;UID = myuserid; PASSWORD = mypassword; DATABASE = mydatabasename;";
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

It shows the error couldn't connect to the database.

P.S: Mysql database is at eu5.org server

Comment: `telnet eu5.org 3306` fails for me.  Is there a reason you think you are in a better position to connect to this server?

Comment: Can you connect by a mysql client? Something like HeidiSql, mysql administrator, etc...

Comment: Check your network, check if the server's running...

Comment: my site is actually a subdomain in eu5.org
Am i using the correct server name

Comment: @Ajay, the server in your connection string is not using a subdomain, so I believe you are not using the correct server name.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer to use the [MySql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) IDE for testing connections and working (Querying) the database directly where possible. Most hosted databases that I have worked with normally define the Server as Instance.[DomainName] so I would have expected your server URL to be something like MySql1.eu5.org

Below is a connection string that I tested using the [MySql Connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), change the parameters.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="server=INSTANCENAME.DOMAINNAME.COM;UID=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;database=DATABASENAME;Persist Security Info=True;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

MAke sure that your server should be started...

Comment: It is on. You can visit the site.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.
Use a browser for MySQL, like http://mysql-query-browser-for-windows.apponic.com/ to check if your database is available.

Comment: yeah, but how can a query a remote database ??

Answer (score 0):

Just read the FAQ:

> Many people want to only use database, but their site is hosted elsewhere. We provide free database for websites hosted with us. For that reason, external access is blocked without exception.

--> http://www.freewebhostingarea.com/faq.html

so it's not possible to access your MySQL-DB from external sources. 
only localhost will be allowed